# How can you rewrite the following equation? $\ln x=-\frac{1}{3}\ln y+C$

Tags: calculus, integration, discrete-mathematics

So I'm having trouble with rewriting my answers, I simply don't know how to start, it goes as follows :
$$\ln x=-\frac{1}{3}\ln y+C$$
becomes :
$$\sqrt[3]{y}=\frac{C}{x}$$
If someone knows the answer and would like to share it, it would be very much appreciated !

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take the cube of both sides: $y=\frac{C^3}{x^3}$. You can replace $C^3$ by $K$, say, where $K$ is any constant (provided $C$ was an arbitrary constant).

Comment: I think what you are asking is, how do you get from $\log x=-(1/3)\log y+C$ to $\root3\of y=C/x$. Is that your question? If so, do you understand why $-(1/3)\log y$ is the same thing as $\log(1/\root3\of y)$? Then do you see what happens if you exponentiate both sides to get rid of the logarithms? After that, the only thing to notice is that if $C$ is an arbitrary constant, then so is $e^C$.

Comment: Thank your @GerryMyerson, So I can replace $e^C$ with C' or another constant, as long as they aren't the same right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems more logical to write

$$\ln y=-3\ln x+c.$$

Then

$$e^{\ln y}=y=e^ce^{-3\ln x}=Cx^{-3}.$$